# Swift Firebase: Token auto-refresh error

Tags: swift, firebase

I am getting the following error message and I understand from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37913470/firebase-authentication-tokens-expiration-duration?noredirect=1&lq=1) that the token to access the Firebase Database expires quickly. This does not allow the users to access the database information. The post does not really explain the solution to extend the database token.

> [Firebase/Auth][I-AUT000003] Token auto-refresh re-scheduled
>   in 01:00 because of error on previous refresh attempt.

I have confirmed that my authentication token is still active, ie `Auth.auth().currentUser` returns a user. How do I extend the token for database access so that users can access data from the database for an infinte amount of time and not restricted to just an hour.

Comment: Any help here pls?

Comment: Any solution?? I'm facing the same issue :(

Comment: @ShahPaneri check ur authentication settings on google cloud platform

Comment: Can you please send me the link where I can see settings for authentication? I found nothing for time limit of authentication in setting.Thanks.