# In Firebase 3.0, how do you set the session timeout?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

In Firebase 3.0, how do you set the session timoeut?  It appears that this was possible in 2.0, but I don't see a way to do this in 3.0.

Comment: In the latest Firebase Authentication SDKs, the sign-in session of the user doesn't normally auto-expire anymore. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37907096/firebase-authentication-duration-is-too-persistent/37908468#37908468

Comment: That's perfect.  Thank you!