# How long does an anonymous Firebase session take to expire?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been trying to figure out Firebase auth and the documentations a little lacking - How long do the firebase anonymous session user UID's last for? Can you use them in multiple sessions?

For example in my android app I'd love to sign in anonymously, close the app, open it the next day, and use the same UID - is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Tokens are in principle valid indefinitely, they no longer auto-expire. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37907096/firebase-authentication-duration-is-too-persistent/37908468#37908468