# In flutter, for how long does an anonymous login persist?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter

I'm wondering specifically what kind of events (other than signing out and possibly disabling an account) that would end the lifetime of an anonymous sign-in.

Does it work the same was as with react native, as this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46143694 ?

> You don't need to set persistence. Firebase handles it for you by
>   default. You just need to call this function to check whether user is
>   logged or not:
>
> firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
>         if (user) {
>           console.log('user is logged');
>         } } This will not be triggered only if user has sign out or cleaned app data.

Can I rely on the anonymous sign-in to persist unless the user signs out, is disabled, or the app is uninstalled?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697185/how-long-does-an-anonymous-firebase-session-take-to-expire, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37907096/firebase-authentication-duration-is-too-persistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can rely on the anonymous account to persist in those cases.  It would not be useful otherwise.

Comment: The wording in this document (https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#anonymous-sign-in) makes it sound like even if you sign-out, the same account will be used next time.  "If the user signs-out and reauthenticates anonymously again, they will be signed-in with the previously created account"...I think this is wrong