# swift firebase auth user write into database expired

Tags: swift, firebase

swift firebase auth user write into database expired, but it still shows user logged in. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37908468/5113880) question of stackflow, it is saying that the token that allows the user to access the Firebase back-end. This token is based on the previous token, is valid for an hour, and is automatically created and refreshed by the Firebase SDKs.

Is it possible to keep the token that allows the user to access the Firebase back-end for 2 weeks or longer?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?